# Evaluate the following integration using Cauchy's Integral formulae.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Consider
$$\int_C\frac {{e^z}^t}{(z^2+1)^2} dz,$$
where $t>0$ and $C$ is the circle $|z| = 3$.

I am able to solve it when $z=i$ and $z=-i$ are two simple poles, but cannot proceed when the same poles with order $2$. Please explain how to proceed in such cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply partial fraction decomposition:$$\frac1{(z^2+1)^2}=\frac14\left(\frac i{z+i}-\frac1{(z+i)^2}-\frac i{z-i}-\frac1{(z-i)^2}\right)$$and therefore$$\frac{e^{zt}}{(z^2+1)^2}=\frac14\left(\frac{ie^{zt}}{z+i}-\frac{e^{zt}}{(z+i)^2}-\frac{ie^{zt}}{z-i}-\frac{e^{zt}}{(z-i)^2}\right).$$And now you can apply Cauchy's integral formula four times to compute your integral.

Comment: Thank you very much for the partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that I suggested this approach because it seemed to me that you wanted to use Cauchy's integral formula, but I would have used the residue theorem insted.

Comment: I was able to do it using residue theorem, but did not have a lead in Cauchy's integral formula. thanks.